# My js function isn't responding in the html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myfunc(){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("enter a guess").value);
    if(y==x){
        alert("Right ans");

        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("wrong ans");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <h1>Enter a guess from 1 to 10</h1>
    <input type="text" id="enter a guess" name="enter a guess" placeholder = "enter a guess">
    <br><br>
    <button class="button"; onclick="myFunc()">Guess</button>
</div>
```

I'm required to take an input int from the user from 1 to 10 and to generate a random number from 1 to 10 if both are equal and the user click the guess button  a message should be displayed to tell him if he is right or wrong also if he is right the page background color should be green else if wrong it should be red

Comment: Typo - you try to call `myFunc()` but function is named `myfunc()`.

Comment: Does your console show an error messages?

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple issues:

`id` can not have spaces in it. You can also not add a semicolon `;` after button `class`.

```html
<div class="center">

    <h1>Enter a guess from 1 to 10</h1>
    
     <input type="text" id="enter_a_guess" name="enter a guess" placeholder = "enter a guess"><br><br>
    <button class="button" onclick="myFunc()">Guess</button>
</div>

    <script>
function myFunc(){
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("enter_a_guess").value);
  if(y==x){
    
    alert("Right ans");

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    alert("wrong ans");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Rajan id name can NOT have spaces in it. Please research before commenting. Also the example code is work above, so what research needs to be done? Please clarify... ***https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id***

Comment: my bad, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simpler:

```js
button.onclick = () => {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
    y = parseInt(enter_a_guess.value),
    col,
    al;
  y == x ? (col = "green", al = "Right!") : (col = "red", al = "Wrong!");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = col;
  alert(al);
};
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <h1>Enter a guess from 1 to 10</h1>
  <input type="text" id="enter_a_guess" name="enter a guess" placeholder="Enter a guess">
  <button class="button" id="button">Guess</button>
</div>
```